# Is it possible to use a current version of Visual Studio to create an ActiveX DLL that can be called from within a VBA project?

Tags: vba, activex

Using the old Developer Tools for Microsoft Office 2000 or Visual Studio 6 (Visual Basic 6), it was possible to create ActiveX DLLs that could be referenced and called from within a VBA project. Is there any way to do this using up-to-date Visual Basic / VBA coding tools?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/walkthrough-creating-com-objects

Comment: I’ve compiled a C++ DMO using VisualStudio 2008 (IIRC!) but I already had the old code and libraries. I don’t know if you can create them.

Comment: DMO = DirectX Media Object?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert myself but here's a small example to get you started. A simple DLL for calculating the total of two numbers written in Visual Studio 2017.

Steps:

1) Create a Class Library project. 
2) Under Assembly Information, select "Make assembly COM-Visible". 
3) Under Build, select "Register for COM interop".

The `ICalculator` interface:

```
[Guid("097E4850-4880-45B8-A20E-AFECC5D11D44")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICalculator
{
    void Calculate(double number1, double number2);
}
```

The `ICalculatorEvents` interface:

```
[Guid("A3C988C8-9DA8-4981-AC11-6653FDDA6B30")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICalculatorEvents
{
    void CalculationSuccessfull(double result);
}
```

The `Calculator`class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ComCalculator
{       
    public delegate void SuccessDelegate(double result);

    [Guid("79B9BB64-AA3A-4FBB-BAAA-0FAC448CC695")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICalculatorEvents))]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public sealed class Calculator : ICalculator
    {
        public event SuccessDelegate CalculationSuccessfull = null;

        public Calculator()
        {
        }

        public void Calculate(double number1, double number2)
        {
            double _calc = 0;
            _calc = number1 + number2;
            OnSuccess(_calc);
        }

        private void OnSuccess(double result)
        {
            CalculationSuccessfull?.Invoke(result);
        }
    }
}
```

In VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents objCalc As ComCalculator.Calculator

Private Sub Calculate()

    Set objCalc = New Calculator
    objCalc.Calculate 7, 5
End Sub

Private Sub objCalc_CalculationSuccessfull(ByVal result As Double)
    Debug.Print result
End Sub

'Output: 12
```

Note:

You will need to run Visual Studio as admin.

Comment: I'm guessing this is C#? I don't know C#, so while there may be very helpful information in that answer, I'm afraid I won't be able to use it without first putting some effort into understanding the C# concepts I'm lacking.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it  appears so.

I Googled "[Create ActiveX DLL](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&q=create%20ActiveX%20DLL)" and the first hit is a Microsoft tutorial on how to create an ActiveX DLL (called `ThingDemo.DLL`) with Visual Studio 6.

[image: example]

Lots of other good links too.

Comment: Yes, with Visual Studio 6 this was easily doable, but I'm wondering if it can also be done with more current versions of Visual Studio. I'm working through the walkthrough linked by Tim Williams above (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/com-interop/walkthrough-creating-com-objects) using Visual Studio 2010, and I'm able to compile the DLL and set a reference to it in the VBA IDE, but when I try to instantiate it (early binding) in VBA, I get run-time error 429.